# Not able to set list item activated in Master/Detail Fragment ICS 4.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am trying to develop application with Master/ Detail (Fragment) layout but I am facing a weird issue that is when i added my own listview adapter then the activation of the listview items on click/select stopped working.

The code provided in default with dummy data was

```
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(
      getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
      android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS));
```

the code that I replaced is

```
    CMyListAdapter adapter = new CMyListAdapter(getActivity(),
            CMyContent.getSampleMyContentList());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, when i click the the listview item, it highlights and doesn't remain persistent.

Comment: Are you using a custom layout for the row?

Comment: yes I am using custom layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a custom layout make sure you are settings the right background drawable:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

In case you want to customize indicator's style you have to define your own `StateListDrawable` xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

   <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

and assign it as your row layout background.